# Dictionary with dataframes as values to Mongo; .to_dict not an option, any way to convert?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I have a dictionary containing 10 keys where the values are pandas dataframes; I need to upload the data to a Mongo database but I cannot convert the dataframes using .to_dict(orient='records'). Can anyone please enlighten me on how I could convert and use my data with Mongo?

I created a sample code, I need to convert the dictionary mydict below to a usable format:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'j':[34,54,55],'k'[4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'m':[3,8,5],'n':[2,3,4]})

mydict={'key1':df1,'key2':df2}
```

since df1 and df2 are dataframes and are within a dictionary, .to_dict is not an option, I also tried looping and converting but cannot think of any other ways.

Comment: Please clarify if that example is already the exact case your looking for,

Comment: it's a sample case that resembles the huge dictionary of data I have, I'm not sure if that answers your question? @MartinSeehafer

Comment: And why is to_dict not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you are looking for:

```
targetdict = {}
for k in mydict:
    targetdict[k] = mydict[k].to_dict()
```